# Yii2 wbraganca dynamic form show and hide fields based on radio button value

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, dynamic-forms

I am using wbraganca dynamic form in popup modal.In this i need to show and validate fields based on radio button selection.So that i call javascript function in onchange event.

```
<?= $form->field($model, "[{$i}]option")->dropDownList(['month'=>'Month','year'=>'Year'],["class"=>"custom-radio-inline","onChange"=>"changeFields($(this))"])->label(false);?>
```

I am trying to get checked value using javascript like below. It's working only first set of fields, if user add another form  it's always return value as 1.

```
function changeFields(item)
{
 var id = "#"+item.attr("id")+" input[type=radio]:checked";
 var val = $(id).val()
 console.log(val);
}
```

In this what i am donig wrong, please help any one, I want show and hide fields based upon this radio button selection and perform validation also based on this selection. **!Important** this i want in every form.

Comment: why aren't you using `when` and `whenClient` in the `rules` inside your `model`

Answer (score 0):

use whenClient in the rules.

```
[['myAtt'], 'required', 'whenClient' => new JsExpression("
    function (attribute, value) {
        console.log(attribute, value);
    }
")]
```

Comment: do you always read others comments and then try to copy answer?